# I'm struggling with this question about arithmetic

Tags: c++, math, integer-arithmetic

The function must return the sum of all integers between from and to including these numbers.
For example, arithmeticSum(2,4) should be 9 because 2+3+4 = 9.

This is the code right now, i can't change anything in the main.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int aritmetiskSumma(int from, int to){
    int i=0;
    int sum=0;
    for(i=1;i<to;i++){
        sum+=i;
    }
  return sum; // TODO
}
// Ändra inget nedanför denna rad
void provaAritmetiskSumma(){
    int from, to;
    cin >> from >> to;
    int summa = aritmetiskSumma(from, to);
    cout << summa << endl;
}
int main(){
    provaAritmetiskSumma();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do not tag C or C# for C++ questions.

Comment: Why does your for loop start at `1`?

Comment: `for(i=1;i<to;i++)` -- Please go through this loop by hand.  Does it do what you wrote on paper?  What if `from` was `1000` and `to` was `2000`?  Does it make sense to start `i` at 1?

Comment: Your `aritmetiskSumma()` function doesn't use the `from` parameter, so you can get rid of the `from` parameter and only use the `to` parameter.  Or you may want to do something like `for (i = from; i < to; ++i) sum += i;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to calculate the sum, adjust the for loop like this:

```
for(; from <= to; from++)
{
   sum += from;
}
```

This code starts with the `from` value and calculates the sum of all the integers up to and including `to`.

Comment: Thank you Filip you made it work :D

Answer (score 0):

You're almost good, just need to fix barriers: you'd like to go exactly from `from`, 0 offset and include `to`:

```
    for(i=from; i<=to; i++){
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `for(i=from;...`, then?

Comment: @NathanPierson Ah, true. Thanks for spotting, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Hej! Your Arithmetic sum function takes in variables "from" and "to", however the function body does not contain your "from" variable. Instead the function is running from i = 1 every time instead of i = from.

Also I believe that i should be less than or equal to "to" in the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem without a loop. The series `1 + 2 + ... + n` is equal to n(n+1)/2 ([Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF)).

We can view the problem of calculating the sum from b + (b + 1) + ... + (e - 1) + e as calculating the values (1 + 2 + ... + (e - 1) + e) - (1 + 2 + ... + (b - 1)), assuming both b and e are positive integers. Both of these terms can be calculated using this formula.

1 + 2 + ... + (e - 1) + e = e(e+1)/2.

1 + 2 + ... + (b - 2) + (b - 1) = (b-1)(b)/2.

Putting these two formulas together we get:

Sum(b,e) = (e(e+1)-(b-1)b)/2.

Using your input given, we have:

Sum(2,4) = (4(4+1) - (2-1)2) / 2 = (4(5) - 1(2)) / 2  = 9.

In code, this would look like this:

```
int sum(int b, int e) {
  if(b == 0) return e * (e + 1) / 2;

  return (e * (e + 1) - (b-1) * b) / 2;
}
```

Once again, this only works for positive b and e.